# Qual a diferença entre o pyautogui.click() para o click do mouse?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Estou fazendo um jogo com PyAutoGUI, no qual  só preciso ficar clicando nas coisas para algo acontecer.

Cada clique conta como 1 de dano em um monstro e eu posso automatizar esses processos matando mais monstros e ganhando dinheiro.

A questão é que esse jogo não me permite usar o `pyautogui.click`. Já tentei fazê-lo clicar só uma vez, tentei randomizar a posição dos cliques, tentei clicar em outros lugares e até mesmo rodei esse jogo no navegador pra ver se era diferente e não, em todos os outros jogos funcionava menos neste.

Segue o código:

```
from pyautogui import *
import random

keyDown('alt')
press('tab')
keyUp('alt')

PAUSE = 0.3

num = 0

while(True):

click(random.randint(1024,1080), random.randint(500,550),clicks = 1, interval = 0.1)    
num += 1
if(num == 10):
    break
```

Comment: Cara, se a indentação estiver desta forma, esse pode ser um dos fatores que está influenciando em seu código não funcionar.

Comment: Dunga, vi que vc tinha revertido as edições, porém a versão original não estava de acordo com o [guia de estilo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/112052) e com [certas diretrizes](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/112052), por isso acabei editando novamente, deixando-a mais sucinta (menos ruído e mais direto ao ponto) e mais adequada à proposta do site. Se for editar novamente, se atente a esses detalhes por favor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O click é composto pela ação de apertar e soltar o botão do mouse. Quando feito por uma pessoa, ele pode demorar mais do que quando feito automaticamente pelo PyAutoGUI, o que significa que outros programas podem detectar robôs que clicam automaticamente medindo o tempo entre as ações.

Felizmente, o PyAutoGUI permite também simular as ações de apertar e soltar o botão separadamente por meio das funções `mouseDown` e `mouseUp` ([ref](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#the-mousedown-and-mouseup-functions)). Fiz um teste e bastou colocar uma função seguida da outra para o click funcionar nesse jogo. Adaptando seu código, ficaria assim:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import random

keyDown('alt')
press('tab')
keyUp('alt')

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.3

num = 0

while(True):
   mouseDown(x=random.randint(1024,1080), y=random.randint(500,550))
   mouseUp()
   num += 1
    
if(num == 10):
   break
```

Note que você deve atribuir um valor à variável `pyautogui.PAUSE` para determinar o intervalo de tempo entre as ações. Atribuir valor a uma variável `PAUSE` como você fez originalmente simplesmente cria uma nova variável sem nenhuma relação com o módulo.

Comment: Eu tinha pensado que era algo relacionado a isso mas não tinha achado esse mouseUp/mouseDown nas referências dskjdsak, muito obrigado!!! o time.sleep eu tinha deixado o pyautogui.Pause, ele já não serve pra demorar entre as ações?

Comment: Sim, o pyautogui.PAUSE funcionaria e é até mais adequado do que o time.sleep, porém você fez de forma errada. Editei a resposta para indicar o erro.

Comment: Entendi, aliás para desencargo de consciência, tem como eu deixar a questão do mouseDown/MouseUp mais rapido? porque diferente do click ele tem um delay bem considerável...

Comment: Você teria que testar diferentes valores de PAUSE, mas lembre-se que cliques muito rápidos são passíveis de serem bloqueados pelo jogo.